# Python: How to make this code look more beautiful ,elegant ,Pythonic ,simple ,shorter?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, mean

This is my code ,it is extremely big for something this simple ,how should i make it better?

```
import numpy

charStats = {'health': 50 ,'damage': 10.1}
charList = []
numbyO = -1
for x in charStats:
    numbyO += 1
    charList.append(charStats[x])
print(int(numpy.mean(charList)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create `charList`; just use `dict.values()`:

```
from statistics import mean

char_stats = {'health': 50 ,'damage': 10.1}
print(int(mean(char_stats.values())))
```

Comment: Something that's easy to miss - `statistics.mean` works with an iterable, including the generator-like `dict_values`.  `np.mean` requires an array, or a list, e.g. `np.mean(list(char_stats.values()))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can creat a class object and reuse this code,,,

```
import numpy                 

class GetMean:
"""make a class object that takes a dict. argument"""
def __init__(self, dict_argument):
    #creat dict. attribute 
    self.dict_argument = dict_argument
    
    #creat list attribute
    self.char_list = []
    
    #creat numby_0 attribute
    self.numby_0 = -1
    
def return_mean(self):
    #method that returns mean
    for x in self.dict_argument:
        self.numby_0 +=1
        self.char_list.append(self.dict_argument[x])
    mean = (int(numpy.mean(self.char_list)))
    return mean


charStats = {'health': 50 ,'damage': 10.1}

get_mean = GetMean(charStats) 
#instanting GetMean object

mean = get_mean.return_mean() 
#using return mean method

 print(mean) #showing result
```

Comment: This is the opposite of simplification; you took OP's unnecessarily complex code and made it even more unnecessarily complex.  There's no reason to use OOP for a simple mathematical operation like this.

Comment: If the code id being for any project,,, oop is as simple as it gets...

Comment: Respectfully: whoever taught you that (probably a Java programmer) is incorrect.  :)  OOP is not always a simplification, and unnecessary OOP usually means unnecessary state, which is the source of most unnecessary complexity (and most bugs).

Comment: Well,, you forgetting the fact that  once you creat a class properly,,, u never have to think about that class again,,,you can use it like a built in function/method provided by python.

Comment: You can use a class "like" a function, just like you can use a screwdriver "like" a hammer by banging things with the handle, but it's simpler to use tools for their intended purpose, and just define a simple function when you need something that acts as a simple function.  Or in this case, just use the built in function that already exists.

Comment: Just trying to save you some hassle, btw.  If you don't want to hear it from me, I promise you that you'll eventually figure it out on your own.  :)  I also learned OOP in school from Java fanatics and went through a phase of trying to staple classes to everything.  Eventually you figure out that you're just wasting your time doing that; if you're lucky, you'll work with code reviewers that speed you along by pointing out that you're wasting *their* time by writing a lot of unnecessary code that they have to review.